# Editing records in binary file C

Tags: c, structure, binaryfiles

I'm working on a C project that's about CRUD operations on records in binary files.
The records are using the **structure** data type.

I'm encountering a problem when updating the records. Here is the function:

```
void modifyGoods(char fileName[]) {

     struct myGood newGood;
     int idNumber, found = 0;

     printf("\nUPDATING THE RECORD...");
     printf("\nEnter the id of the record you would like to update: ");
     scanf("%d", &idNumber);

     FILE* filePointer = fopen(fileName, "rb+");

     while ((fread(&newGood, sizeof(newGood), 1, filePointer)) > 0 && found == 0) {
         if (newGood.id == idNumber) {

// new data of the record
             printf("\nEnter the new data:\n");

             printf("Category: ");
             scanf("%s", &newGood.category);

             printf("Description: ");
             scanf("%s", &newGood.description);

             printf("Price: ");
             scanf("%f", &newGood.price);

             printf("Quantity: ");
             scanf("%d", &newGood.quantity);

// go one record back in order to overwrite the record that needs to be updated
             fseek(filePointer, -(long)sizeof(newGood), SEEK_CUR);
//overwrites record
             fwrite(&newGood, sizeof(newGood), 1, filePointer);
             
             printf("Record updated!\n");
             found = 1;
             printf("%d", found);

         }
     }

     fclose(filePointer);
     if (found == 0) {
         printf("\nERROR! THIS ID DOESN'T EXIST!\n\n");
     }

}
```

If I update the FIRST record of the binary file, it works as expected, but if I try to update any record after the first one, this happens:

A B C - records in a binary file.

If I try to update B then it becomes: A B (updated) B (old record).

The record gets updated but the ones after him is overwritten with the old value of the second one.

How should I approach this problem? I changed the offset of the fseek function but still doesn't work.

Thank you,
Marco

Comment: That would only happen if the `fseek()` failed.

Comment: I don't know what goes on beyond this, but you will read two records this way. After the first loop, it'll first read again and then stop because found != 0.

Comment: @EmanuelP `found == 0` means to keep going, not stop.

Comment: Switch the conditions around for your while loop to avoid an extra `fread()` -- right now it performs the read before checking `found`, so it does one extra read after `found` is changed even though it doesn't enter the loop body again.  It's probably harmless since all you do after the extra read is close the file, though.

Answer (score 1):

First of all,

> ```
>  scanf("%d", &idNumber);
> ```

How do you know scanf succeeded?  If the user just pressed enter, are you willing  to accept whatever value happened to be in `idNumber` when it was defined?

Test *every single return code*. About the only one you can safely ignore is when closing a file. (It hardly ever happens and, if it does, what can you do?)

I'm not sure what's going wrong with your program, but I have two suggestions that may help.

1. Instead of seeking back some fixed distance, use **ftell**(3) to record the position prior to calling **fread**.  Then, when you want to overwrite the record, seek to the recorded location.  That way, if the record size changes (or you guessed wrong to start with) the logic still works.
2. Use a break instead of a boolean to exit the loop.  Your professor might say it's not structured code, but your colleagues won't mind.

You add ftell by switching to a `for` loop:

```
size_t len;
for( off_t pos=ftell(filePointer); 
     (len = fread(&newGood, sizeof(newGood), 1, filePointer)) == sizeof(newGood; 
     pos=ftell(filePointer) ) {
  ...
  if( -1 == fseek(filePointer, pos, SEEK_SET) ) {
    err(EXIT_FAILURE, "could not seek");
  }
  if (newGood.id != idNumber) {
     continue;
  } 

  //overwrites record
  if( sizeof(newGood) != fwrite(&newGood, sizeof(newGood), 1, filePointer) ) {
    err(EXIT_FAILURE, "could not write");
  }
         
  printf("Record updated!\n");
  found = 1;
  printf("%d", found);
  break;
}
```

One other point: When you exit the loop, you assume if found is 0 the record was not found. **fread**(3) can return 0 on error, causing the loop to exit, in which case it's a little misleading to tell the user the record's not there.